# Applying condition to multiple columns in R

Tags: r, market-basket-analysis, dummy-variable

I have a dataset which represents a basket for each customer in the form of dummy variables.

for example:

```
P1  P2  P3  P4  P5
0   2   0   0   0
0   1   0   0   0
0   0   0   3   0 
0   0   0   0   0
0   0   5   0   0
1   1   0   0   0
```

Where P1 represents product 1 and so on.

Essentially, I would like to run a simple query in which I can convert all the values which are more than 1 to 1. This way I will have only 1s and 0s in my data. I was able to do it for a few rows using:

```
df[(df$P1>1] <- 1
```

Is there an apply all function?

Answer (score 6):

You can convert to a logical matrix and coerce to binary by wrapping with `+`.

```
+(df > 0)
#     P1 P2 P3 P4 P5
#[1,]  0  1  0  0  0
#[2,]  0  1  0  0  0
#[3,]  0  0  0  1  0
#[4,]  0  0  0  0  0
#[5,]  0  0  1  0  0
#[6,]  1  1  0  0  0
```

Or use slightly slower `ifelse`

```
ifelse(df > 0, 1, 0)
```

---

If the dataset is really big, creating a `matrix` may not be memory efficient.  We can convert to `data.table` (assuming that the initial dataset is `data.frame`) and use `set` to change the values to 1

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
for(j in seq_along(df)){
  set(df, i= which(df[[j]] > 1), j=j, value=1)
 }

df
#   P1 P2 P3 P4 P5
#1:  0  1  0  0  0
#2:  0  1  0  0  0
#3:  0  0  0  1  0
#4:  0  0  0  0  0
#5:  0  0  1  0  0
#6:  1  1  0  0  0
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work along the same lines as what you tried:

```
df[df > 0] <- 1
df
  P1 P2 P3 P4 P5
1  0  1  0  0  0
2  0  1  0  0  0
3  0  0  0  1  0
4  0  0  0  0  0
5  0  0  1  0  0
6  1  1  0  0  0
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not playing with `class` as well:

```
`class<-`(!!df, "numeric")

#     P1 P2 P3 P4 P5
#[1,]  0  1  0  0  0
#[2,]  0  1  0  0  0
#[3,]  0  0  0  1  0
#[4,]  0  0  0  0  0
#[5,]  0  0  1  0  0
#[6,]  1  1  0  0  0
```